# Triggering a function after two mouseenter events

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

Im trying to get some practice with JS and i have two circles which scale up in size with "mouseenter" by adding the hover class to the circles.  What I want is once both circles have the hover class, the "laser" element shows itself via display="block".  Even though the mouseenter functions work, the "laser" element is never triggered.  Is this because the JS has already loaded before the mouseenter conditionals have been met?  Should I be using an event listener to listen for the hovers or is there a better way to make this work.

```
const circle = document.querySelector('#circle');

const circleTwo = document.querySelector('#circle2');

if (circle !== null) {
    circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    circle.classList.add('hover');
    });
}

if (circleTwo !== null) {
    circleTwo.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        circleTwo.classList.add('hover');    
    });
};


if (circleTwo.classList.contains('hover') && circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    document.getElementById("laser").style.display = "block"
};
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script> 
    <title>Something Else</title>
    <style>
        body { background-color: gray; background-image: url(images/acid.gif); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="circle">Text</div> 
        <div id="circle2">Text</div> 
        <a href="laser.html"><img src="images/laserEyes.png" id="laser"></a>
    </div>
    
    

        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues.

1. You don't remove the hover class. You can easily listen for a mouseleave event and remove it then.
2. Your if statement only executes once. You should add it to the event handler.

You could just use 1 handler function for both events:

```js
const circleMouseenterHandler = e => {
  e.target.classList.add('hover');

  if (circleTwo.classList.contains('hover') && circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    document.getElementById("laser").style.display = "block"
  };
}
circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', circleMouseenterHandler);
circleTwo.addEventListener('mouseenter', circleMouseenterHandler);

//Removing:
const circleMouseleaveHandler = e => {
  e.target.classList.remove('hover');
}
circle.addEventListener('mouseleave', circleMouseleaveHandler);
circleTwo.addEventListener('mouseleave', circleMouseleaveHandler);
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works and thank you.  Not sure I understand the need to remove the hover class as I dont believe your example does so.

Comment: You need to remove the hover class because otherwise it would trigger the laser showing by 
1. Hovering over first circle
2. Unhovering (?) over the first circle 
3. Hovering over the second circle.
Also I've updated the answer to include removing the hover class